# grafana - diplay series summed up

Tags: grafana

imagine you have a time series graph showing multiple fields. One field is an "overall" field like - total power consumtion, and other fields are showing parts of that "overall" graph, like power meters in several power outlets.

I wonder if i can display the power outlets in a stacked up way so they visually get all added up - but still show as independent graph. It just does not start at 0 but on top of an other graph. That way i could visually see the power which is consumed by other outlets not having any power meters.

What i have now:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

The 200W is "added" onto the 100W Graph so I can now visually see, I have power meters for 300W, but overall I use 400W, so 100W is "missing".

I achived that several years ago - most likeley with the old time series graph, but unfortunally I can't remember how.... which graph was lowest in the chart and which highest was iirc based on the order of the selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to panel options: Graph styles > Stack series > Select `Normal`. It will stack all time series.

Then go to Overrides tab.

1. <kbd>Add field overried</kbd>  > Field with name > Select `Total`.
2. <kbd>Add override property</kbd>  > Graph styles > Stack series > Select `Off`

Comment: Yeah tried that but that one looks super crazy because if you have 2 measurements at second 5 and second 10 for graph A, and only one measurement at second 7 for graph B, it stacks up not in an expected way. it shows second 5 and 10 with B=0 and second 7 with A=0 because it has no recorded values at those times. Usually the graphs are filling in missing times - but when stacking is chosen they stop filling in "missing" times - and so the whole graph gets broken because of course - not all power meters measure at the exact same second.

Comment: OK - i think I found the issue - i had fill(null) for each measurement. Setting this to fill(linear) seems to solve it :)